# Pygame, livewires: Attribute error: Message object has no attribute 'handle collide'

Tags: python, pygame, livewires

I'm making a game using the special 'pygame' and 'livewires' from *Python Programming For The Absolute Beginner* and it's working pretty well, for the most part. At the moment you can play the game, a timer will tick by and then when a spike hits you the text 'Lose! Time:' and then whatever time you got to will appear. However, despite having a message lifetime of 300, the message lasts for less than a second as the screen closes and you see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "run.py", line 105, in main
        games.screen.mainloop()
    File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py, line 308, in mainloop


       object._tick()
    File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", live 506, in _tick
        self.update()
    File "run.py", line 27, in update
        self.check_collide()
    File "run.py", line 34, in check_collide
        spike.handle_collide()
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'handle_collide'
```

Woah. Here is the relevant code (by my judgement):

```
class Player(games.Sprite):
    """The player that must dodge the spikes."""

    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__(image=image, x=x, y=y)
        """
        Timer
        """
        self.timer = games.Text(value = 0,
                            size = 40,
                            color = color.black,
                            x = 600,
                            y = 440)
        games.screen.add(self.timer)

    def update(self):
        """Move to the mouse."""
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        self.y = games.mouse.y
        self.check_collide()
        self.timer.value = int(time.clock())


    def check_collide(self):
        """Check for a collision with the spikes."""
        for spike in self.overlapping_sprites:
            spike.handle_collide()



class Spike(games.Sprite):
    """A spike!"""

    def update(self):
        """Move to the left!"""
        self.x -= random.randrange(3,12)
        if self.x == 0 or self.x == 1 or self.x == 2 or self.x == 3 or self.x == 4 or self.x == 5 or self.x == 6 or self.x < 10:
            self.x = 640
            self.y = random.randrange(games.screen.height)

    def handle_collide(self):
        """Destroy!"""

        timebomb = int(time.clock())
        man = ("Lose! Time:",timebomb)
        lost_message = games.Message(value = man,
                            size = 100,
                            color = color.red,
                            x = games.screen.width/2,
                            y = games.screen.height/2,
                            lifetime = 300,
                            after_death = games.screen.quit)
        games.screen.add(lost_message)
```

I'm confused. The method `handle_collide` is supposed to be called so the game can finish, but it seems it things handle_collide is an attribute for the object message? If this seems stupid then sorry because I have honestly tried my best with this and , as the book name implies, I am a noob. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the error is in `Player.check_collide`. What is `self.overlapping_sprites`? Is is possible that it contains non-`Spike` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix.

```
def check_collide(self):
    """Check for a collision with the spikes."""
    for spike in self.overlapping_sprites:
        spike.handle_collide()
```

The '*spike*' in the for loop is just the name for whatever is colliding with the player. What's actually happening is the player is colliding with the 'Message' object and then asking for the message object's way of dealing with sprite collisions. The message object isn't prepared and doesn't have a '*handle_collide*' method to deal with this. So it throws an error. To fix it you can just move the text away from the player, or play around with the 'Message' object and create the method that the for loop is expecting.

Comment: To elaborate on the 'playing around with the message and text classes' part, just go into the pygame (or for me livewires) classes for text and message and create a method for your code, in my case, handle_collide.